# How do I add a file selector in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to add a file selector to my extension for chrome, I cant seem to be able. How do I do it?

I have searched the internet far and wide, people are saying you have to do it in html, but I have seen a github page with a working file selector

Comment: `selector = document.createElement("input"); selector.type = "file"; document.body.appendChild(selector);`